# A proof that $\sum_{i=0}^{p_n-1} f(Y_{t_i^n})(X_{t_{i+1}^n}-X_{t_i^n})^2$ converges a.s. to $\int_0^t f(Y_s)\mathrm{d}\langle X, X\rangle_s$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Let $X = (X_t, t\ge 0)$ be a continuous square-integrable martingale and $\langle X, X\rangle$ its quadratic variation. Let $Y = (Y_t, t\ge 0)$ be a process with continuous trajectories. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. I'm trying to prove below result used in the proof of Itô's lemma, i.e,

> **Theorem**  For each $t>0$, there is an increasing sequence $0=t_0^n<\cdots<t_{p_n}^n=t$ of subdivisions of $[0, t]$ whose mesh tends to $0$ and that
> $$
> \sum_{i=0}^{p_n-1} f (Y_{t_i^n}) (X_{t_{i+1}^n}-X_{t_i^n})^2 \quad  \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \quad \int_0^t f (Y_s) \mathrm{d}\langle X, X\rangle_s
> \quad \text{almost surely}.
> $$

Could you have a check if my below attempt is fine?

---

**Proof** Clearly, there is an increasing sequence $0=t_0^n<\cdots<t_{p_n}^n=t$ of subdivisions of $[0, t]$ whose mesh tends to $0$. We note that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{p_n-1} f (Y_{t_i^n}) (X_{t_{i+1}^n}-X_{t_i^n})^2 = \int_{[0, t]} f(Y_s) \mathrm d \mu_n (s),
$$
where $\mu_n$ is the random (discrete) measure on $[0, t]$ defined by
$$
\mu_n := \sum_{i=0}^{p_n-1} (X_{t_{i+1}^n}-X_{t_i^n})^2 \delta_{t_i^n}.
$$

Let $D$ be the set that consists of all $t_i^n$ for $n \geq 1$ and $0 \leq i \leq p_n$. Then $D$ is dense in $[0, t]$.

> **Lemma** For every sequence $0=t_0^n<\cdots<t_{p_n}^n=t$ of sub-divisions of $[0, t]$ whose mesh tends to $0$, we have
> $$
> \sum_{i=0}^{p_n-1} (X_{t_{i+1}^n} - X_{t_i^n})^2 \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \langle X, X \rangle_t \quad \text{in probability}.
> $$

By above **Lemma**, we get for every $r \in D$,
$$
\mu_n([0, r]) \quad \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \quad \langle X, X\rangle_r \quad \text{in probability}.
$$

So there is a subsequence of values of $n$ such that, along this subsequence, we have for every $r \in D$,
$$
\mu_n([0, r]) \quad \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \quad \langle X, X\rangle_r \quad \text{almost surely}.
$$

This [implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630330/if-lim-n-mu-n-0-r-mu-0-r-for-all-r-in-d-then-mu-n-to-mu) that the sequence $(\mu_n, n \in \mathbb N)$ of random measures converges almost surely to a random measure $\mu$ (whose random c.d.f. is $\langle X, X\rangle_r \mathbf{1}_{[0, t]}(r)$) in the sense that
$$
\mu_n (\omega) \quad \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}\quad\mu(\omega)  \quad \text{in distribution}
$$
for $\mathbb P$-a.e. $\omega \in \Omega$. On the other hand, convergence in distribution is equivalent to [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures?useskin=vector#Weak_convergence_of_measures). Hence
$$
\int_0^t f(Y_s ) \mathrm d \mu_n (s) \quad \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \quad \int_0^t f(Y_s) \mathrm d \mu(s) = \int_0^t f(Y_s) \mathrm{d} \langle X, X\rangle_s  \quad \text{almost surely}.
$$

This completes the proof.